# Why isn't there an ethics tag

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Why is there no [ethics](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) tag?

Why doesn't anyone create one?

For instance, it could be used to discuss ethics in movies, as well as the ethics of movie making.

Answer (score 2):

Tags aren't created *in advance of questions being asked*, they're created *in response to a question being asked that doesn't match any existing tags*. That's why we don't have a [star-wars-17](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-17) tag, despite the likelihood that we'll eventually need it.

If you want to ask some questions about movie-making ethics, providing they're not opinion-based or too vague to be sensibly answered, your desired tag will end up existing.